# Python scraping href iinks

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

My goal is to scrape href links on the base_url site.

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import requests, csv, re

game_links = []
link_pages = []
base_url = "http://www.basket.fi/sarjat/ohjelma_tulokset/?season_id=93783&league_id=4#mbt:2-303$f&stage=177155:$p&0="


browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get(base_url)
table = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
for game in table.find_all("a", {'game_id': re.compile('\d+')}):
    href=game.get("href")
    print(href)
```

Result:

```
http://www.basket.fi/sarjat/ottelu/?game_id=3502579&season_id=93783&league_id=4
http://www.basket.fi/sarjat/ottelu/?game_id=3502579&season_id=93783&league_id=4
http://www.basket.fi/sarjat/ottelu/?game_id=3502523&season_id=93783&league_id=4
http://www.basket.fi/sarjat/ottelu/?game_id=3502523&season_id=93783&league_id=4

......
```

The problem is that I can't understand why in the result the href links will come always two times?

Comment: the links may appear twice in the page ? you could use a `set()` to filter the doubles (humm, not sure its working with tag objects...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As you Notice in the image there are same game_id for two links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRhOm.png)

Modified Code:
[This would help you to get only one link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfXje.png)

```
for game in table.find_all("a", {'game_id': re.compile('\d+')}):
    if game.children:
        href=game.get("href")
        print(href)
```